# List of all files in a commit for every commit

Tags: bash, git, git-diff, git-log

I'd like to know the name and status of every file in every commit, if the same file is modified twice then it should appear twice in the list.

The following command only prints each file once.

```
git diff --name-status <START> <END>
```

Comment: By status do you mean "added/modified/deleted"?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Note that every commit contains *every* file (or rather, every file it contains: if you "deleted" a file, that means the later commit lacks the file, and if you "added" a file, that means the earlier commit lacks the file). What you're looking for is to have Git tell you about *differences between* the files in *pairs* of <before,after> commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to output info on a series of commits here, not on a diff, so your `diff` command seems not to be the best tool.

I'll suggest the following (feel free to adapt the format, or even use `--pretty=format:""` to just output files lists (one per commit)

```
git log --name-status --pretty=format:"%h %s" <start>^..<end>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer ; #nitpicking : the OP probably doesn't need the `^` after `<start>`. I also like mentioning the `--graph` option, which IMHO makes the log view way clearer (especially when a merge kicks in)

Comment: @LeGEC I share your doubt about the starting point, it was unclear from the question itself, and OP didn't clarify yet, but... they maybe will?

Comment: Consider also adding `-m` to the `git log` so as to split merges into two virtual commits. The default is never to do a diff at all for any merge commit, which is ... misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: @torek I went to [read it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--m). How did I miss that gem of an option, thank you for the tip.

Comment: Note that this documentation, and the fancy format options including `--diff-merges=first-parent`, are new. The `-m` flag has been around since ancient times.

Comment: @torek Haha of course, it's not the option that's *too new*, but rather me. I used `--first-parent` from time to time, but managed to stay unaware of `-m` until now somehow

Comment: The `--first-parent` option to `git log` and `git rev-list` are old, but the `--diff-merges=first-parent` option is new: it means that, regardless of how the commit revision walk goes, treat the merge commit itself as if it has just the first parent for the purpose of doing the diff. So you only get the "mainline diff". That's probably what the default should have been since 2005. I haven't checked on the final resolution, but it might also be the default now when using `--first-parent`. (There was a LOT of argument over this on the mailing list...)